# Comparing multiple hurdle to compensatory scoring (of tests)

Tags: correlation, model-comparison

I plan to do both Monte Carlo and real world research to compare the efficacy of three approaches to combining test scores: (1) fully compensatory scoring, (2) multiple hurdle, and (3) a combination of multiple hurdle and compensatory scoring. In the MC study, the predictors and criterion are all ~N(0,1).  In the real world, the test scores are in terms of percent correct, and the criterion is at least ordinal.  In my field, the efficacy of a predictor is typically evaluated in terms of its correlation with a criterion.

The question is, what statistical analyses might I consider to compare the three approaches to combining predictors.

If this is too terse, let me know and I can flesh it out more.

Clarification: The compensatory scoring in #3 is not "full" because a failing score on one predictor will not be counterbalanced by high scores on other predictors.  The compensatory score in #3 will be "failure" if the score on any predictor is "failure".  Otherwise, the compensatory score in #3 will be the sum of the scores on the predictors.

Comment: any difference between "criterion" and "criterion score", "fully compensatory scoring" and " compensatory scoring"?

Comment: @user158565. TY for your comment. I have edited the post to answer your questions.